# How to make transparent toolbar with not transparent toolbar items

Tags: android, android-toolbar, toolbaritems

how i can to make transparent custom toolbar with visible toolbar items?
I have a page with recycler view and I want to see my recyclerview under mine transparent toolbar with visible toolbar items.
It's should looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLuFL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
 android:background="@drawable/background_toolbar" />
```

now create a background_toolbar.xml in res/drawble

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:startColor="#66000000"/>
</shape>
```

**now set your toolbar**

Comment: @Nielsh Rathod ,your solution is not working as I want to. Okey, look here again. I have a page with recyclerview,so i want to see mine recyclerview under my transparent toolbar.

Comment: add you full screen with quetion i did not get you

Comment: you got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Most Welcome @Vaniusha

Answer (score 0):

set toolbar like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tbsobre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```